# Pérdida de valores de vectores en el programa principal tras usar una función en C

Tags: c, funciones

Tengo un problema con un programa (iterativo.c), desde el que llamo a una función que está en LeeArchivos.c que le pasa X e Y por referencia.
Esa función guarda en X y en Y unos datos que tengo en un txt (el primer dato que guarda es para el numero de parejas de X e Y que hay). El tema es que esto lo hace bien ya que lo he comprobado con printf dentro de la función pero al usar X e Y en el programa principal, han perdido los valores y el calculo final sale mal, da siempre: -1.#QNAN0

Este es el iterativo.c :

```
 #include "header.h"
 int main(){
 int N, i;                                      
 float *x = malloc(sizeof(float)), *y = malloc(sizeof(float));
 float m, sumprod=0, sum_x=0, sum_y=0, sum_x2=0;

 N = LeeArchivos(x,y);

 for(i=0; i<N ; i++){
    sumprod += x[i]*y[i];
    sum_x += x[i];
    sum_y += y[i];
    sum_x2 += cuadrado(x[i]);
}

m = (sumprod - (sum_x * sum_y)/N) / (sum_x2 - (cuadrado(sum_x))/N) ;

  free(x); free(y);

  printf("\nEl valor de la pendiente es %f", m);

  return 0;
  }
```

Este es LeeArchivos.c :

```
#include "header.h"
int LeeArchivos(float* x, float* y) {

int n,i;
char nombrearchivo[15];
FILE *data;

printf("\nIntroduzca el nombre del archivo de datos:");
scanf("%s", nombrearchivo);

if((data = fopen(nombrearchivo , "r")) != NULL) {
   fscanf(data, "%d", &n);
   x = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float) * n);
   y = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float) * n);
   for(i=0; i<n ; i++){
    fscanf(data, "%f", &x[i]);
    fscanf(data, "%f", &y[i]);
   }
   fclose(data);
}

else printf("\n Error al abrir el archivo");

return n;
}
```

Y esta es la cabecera:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define cuadrado(x) ((x)*(x))

int LeeArchivos(float* x, float* y);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu problema está aquí:

```
int LeeArchivos( float* x, float* y ) {
```

Efectivamente, recibes unos punteros a `float` ... mejor dicho, recibes **una copia de unos punteros a `float`**.

Luego, haces

```
x = (float*)malloc( sizeof( float ) * n );
y = (float*)malloc( sizeof( float ) * n );
```

Con lo cual estas modificando **tu copia** de los punteros. Los punteros originales, aquellos que envías desde el `main`, **no han cambiando en absoluto**, y siguen manteniendo sus direcciones originales.

Por otra parte, esto que haces en el `main( )`:

```
float *x = malloc( sizeof( float ) ), *y = malloc( sizeof( float ) );
```

No tiene ningún sentido y no sirve para nada.

Tu código en el `main( )` debería ser:

```
float *x, *y;
```

Tu función LeeArchivos debería ser

```
int LeeArchivos( float **x, float **y ) {
  ...
  if( ( data = fopen( nombrearchivo , "r" ) ) != NULL ) {
    fscanf( data, "%d", &n );

    *x = (float*)malloc( sizeof( float ) * n );
    *y = (float*)malloc( sizeof( float ) * n );

    for( i = 0; i < n ; ++i ) {
      fscanf( data, "%f", &( ( *x )[i] ) );
      fscanf( data, "%f", &( ( *y )[i] ) );
    }

    fclose( data );
  }
...
}
```

Y deberías llamarla desde el `main( )` así:

```
N = LeeArchivos( &x, &y );
```

Con eso debería bastar. Por supuesto, no te olvides de cambiar tu archivo de cabecera.

Comment: Ya he cambiado los errores pero ahora al ejecutar no hace nada por alguna razón que se me escapa... solo pone : Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005) pero no hace el printf con la solución

Comment: Pues no sabría decirte, **aparentemente** está bien ... cambia *temporalmente* `LeeArchivos( float* x, float* y )` para que trabaje con *array* fijos de datos, sin leer ningún archivo, y comprueba el comportamiento y el resultado.

Comment: puedes complementar tu consulta con una archivo de entrada tipo y un resultado esperado, para trazar el comportamiento y establecer que la funcionalidad desarrollada esta correcta.

Comment: acabo de hacer una respuesta con esa información

Comment: @ThunderZ Fallo mio. Que tengo la cabeza en otra parte. Corregido, prueba ahora :-)

Comment: Muchismas GRACIAS ya funciona . Llevaba todo el dia dandole vueltas !

Answer (score 0):

El tipo de archivo de entrada es:

9
7 2
1 9
10 2
5  5
4 7
3 11
13 2
10 7
2 14

El primer numero es el numero de parejas de datos que lo uso para dimensionar dinamicamente los vectores. Una vez se da valor a los vectores se usan para hacer una serie de operaciones matemáticas que he revisado y no tienen mayor relevancia, y como resultado da la pendiente de la recta de minimos cuadrados de esas parejas de puntos en la variable m.

Pero el problema es que al ejecutar no imprime el valor de m, es como si terminase el programa de forma repentina en algun punto y me temo que es en la función pero no se por qué. Pongo el código que se supone que debería funcionar:

```
 #include "header.h"
 int main(){
 int N, i;                                      
 float *x ,*y;
 float m, sumprod=0, sum_x=0, sum_y=0, sum_x2=0;

 N = LeeArchivos( &x, &y );

 for(i=0; i<N ; i++){
     sumprod += x[i] * y[i];
     sum_x += x[i];
     sum_y += y[i];
    sum_x2 += cuadrado(x[i]);
 }

 m = (sumprod - (sum_x * sum_y)/N) / (sum_x2 - (cuadrado(sum_x))/N) ;

 free(x); free(y);

 printf("\nEl valor de la pendiente es %f", m);

 return 0;
 }
```

La funcion:

```
 #include "header.h"

 int LeeArchivos( float **x, float **y ) {

 int n,i;
 char nombrearchivo[15];
 FILE *data;

 printf("\nIntroduzca el nombre del archivo de datos:  ");
 scanf("%s", nombrearchivo);

 if( ( data = fopen( nombrearchivo , "r") ) != NULL ) {
     fscanf( data, "%d", &n );

     *x = (float*)malloc( sizeof( float ) * n );
     *y = (float*)malloc( sizeof( float ) * n );

     for( i = 0; i<n ; i++ ) {
        fscanf( data, "%f", x[i] );
        fscanf( data, "%f", y[i] );
     }   

     fclose(data);
 }

 else printf( "\n Error al abrir el archivo" );

 return n;
 }
```

Y la cabecera tambien actualizada:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdbool.h>
 #define cuadrado(x) ((x)*(x))

 int LeeArchivos( float ** x, float ** y) ;
```